# FastICA of orthonormal inputs

Tags: independent-component-analysis

In Wikipedia page of FastICA it says

> FastICA seeks an orthogonal rotation of prewhitened data

Which means if the input is orthonormal, so would be the output. This can be examined numerically but I cannot find any sources regarding this statement for general case. Also an analytical proof through the algorithm is very hard to carry on because of the randomized initial weighting vector.

Can anyone introduce a source for the above-mentioned statement or guide me on how to develop a proof for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long research still I could not find where this has been originated, but since it is mentioned in a paper (doi:10.1109/TNN.2011.2106511) then I just used that as citation.